# Sql server error message "the database is read only" in a remotely server - availability database

Tags: sql-server, clustering, high-availability, read-only-database

I have a failover cluster with a high availability sql server service, the problem is that I cannot create a table, update, delete remotely even if I already give specific permissions and i had already made the request "ALTER DATABASE [****] SET READ_WRITE".

I don't understand why I always get the "database is read only" error message every time.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you configured Availability Groups ?, If so you have read_only replicas you cannot write on secondary replicas.

Comment: Do you have a listener set up? How are you connecting to the server when you are issuing 'create a table' command?

Comment: Please give more information about the HA configuration and the steps you do (specifying on which server you run which command).